# Why is hard coding username password security threat in php?

Tags: php, websecurity

I have basic login system in php . the form on index page submits username and password to same page using  `POST` method .The username and password are hard coded .
Here is php code on index page that handles

```
if( isset ($_POST['submit']) ) {
$username='Admin';
$password='root';

  if(  ( $_POST['uname'] == $username ) && ( $_POST['pass'] == $password) ) {
         // Redirect to admin page
  } 
  else{
       echo "Wrong credential";
 }

}
```

I have referred to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631879/php-login-system-hard-coded-username-and-password)  but unable to understand why hard coding is bad in these case .

my arguments

1. This eliminates sql injection possibility
2. Source code will never been seen if error reporting is off.

Comment: Hardcoding the credentials isn't the problem. The problem is when you hardcode them in plain text. If the credentials are hardcoded, you can still run both the username/password through `password_hash()` and only store the results (the hashes) in the file and then verify them using `password_verify()`. Why you can hash the username as well is because you don't need to search for the username anywhere and it will also be protected from nosy people.

Comment: One argument: If the php handler is misconfigured you can see the plain text of the source. This may happen during updates of mod-apache for example.

Comment: Another argument: If you use version control software like git, you would expose the credentials.

Comment: hardcoding creds isn't problem, if you store it on hash, but the problem is you cant change creds without redeploying , that so bad

Comment: As written I am pretty sure you could just break it if `uname` and `pass` were to be boolean `true`. Because of how PHP tries to transform the values to be comparable, the string will become boolean true.

A simple error like this would allow someone to easily bypass the authentication.

Comment: Hardcoding will make it difficult to  manage and edit  your source code .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using database this doesn't eliminates sql injection possibility.
You should store username and password in database, store these thought some hashing algorithm for example SHA1, and apply "golden rule filter inputs and escape outputs".

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding is not a security threat. it's a bad practice.
Also @tobias comment of  `uname`  or  `pass` being Boolean  is not harmful. All  inputs are treated as string in php